# Proper way to remove web directory from the path twig function in the url

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, twig

I'm trying to install my local symfony application on a remote server.
The application is currently installed in a public directory.
So I can access my app with `www.mysite.com/public/web`

To get rid off the `public/web` part, I created a `.htaccess` in the server root with the following :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/web/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/web/$1 [L]
```

Now, I can access with `www.mysite.com` and it's work fine !
But, all the link and the assets have kept the `public/web` part.

It works, but I want to remove this part.

There is probably a configuration with the `twig` function `path` and `asset`, but I can't find it.
Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit the apache/vhosts config?

Comment: Yes I can, what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your document root.

My vhost config looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.com
  DocumentRoot /full/path/to/public/web/symfony-project/web
  DirectoryIndex app.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I can't try it before tomorrow, but I will not forget to accept your answer if it's fit ;)

Comment: Ok, fine ! 
Now, I have an issue with the upload files, but I have the solution, thanks !